# Trying to setting a range for abline in R

Tags: r

When I use the abline in `R` ,

```
plot(NULL,xlim=c(0,50),ylim=c(-30,0))
abline(h=-15,col='black')
```

how do I set the range of x axis to a certain range?

(like a horizontal line at `y=-15`,but end with `x =50`) (not using `xlim`)

Comment: Hello OP,

I have provided an answer below yesterday. Please check it out and react to it. If it does not meet your expectation, please clarify the problem. If it did resolve your question, please consider marking it as accepted with the gray check to its left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lines()` function, taking an `x` and `y` coordinate of start/end point. This example has starting point `(0|-15)` and end point `(50|-15)`:

```
lines(x=c(0,50), y=c(-15,-15))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! I have solved it and I think it looks fine!